# Is it possible to play ogg file using c# in Xcode?

Tags: c#, xcode, unity-game-engine, ogg

I have audio files that have to be looped, but it adds short silence when I make mp3 files. Wav files are too big to use. My only option looks like ogg file, but I've been struggling with playing ogg file using c# in Xcode. Can I get some help?

Comment: C# in Xcode? How's that even possible?